# Java BigInteger Out of memory, possibly from long conversion

Tags: java, c, cpu-registers, encryption

I'm trying to convert this KeeLoq algorithm from C into Java but my decryption method seems to use too much memory for Java's BigInteger.  I was wondering if there was an equivalent operation that would work with Java's BigInteger.

The original calculations for the index and bitVal variables are commented out below.

The original source code I'm using as an example can be found here:
https://github.com/franksmicro/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Keeloq/Keeloq.cpp

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
package keeloq;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class KeeLoq {

    BigInteger _keyHigh, _keyLow, keyHigh, keyLow;
    int KeeLoq_code = 0x3A5C742E;
    BigInteger KeeLoq_NLF = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(KeeLoq_code));

    public KeeLoq() {
    }

    public KeeLoq(BigInteger keyHigh, BigInteger keyLow) {
        _keyHigh = keyHigh;
        _keyLow = keyLow;
    }

    public BigInteger bitRead(BigInteger x, int n) {
        BigInteger temp = x.shiftRight(n);
        return temp;
    }

    public BigInteger multiplyBig(BigInteger x, BigInteger n) {
        BigInteger temp = x.multiply(n);
        return temp;
    }

    public BigInteger Encrypt(BigInteger data) {
        BigInteger x = data;
        int keyBitNo;
        long index;
        long position1, position2, position3, position4, position5;
        BigInteger keyBitVal, bitVal;
        BigInteger b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

        for (int r = 0; r < 528; r++) {
            keyBitNo = r & 63;
            if (keyBitNo < 32) {
                keyBitVal = bitRead(_keyLow, keyBitNo);
            } else {
                keyBitVal = bitRead(_keyHigh, keyBitNo - 32);
            }

            position1 = bitRead(x, 1).longValue() * 1;
            position2 = bitRead(x, 9).longValue() * 2;
            position3 = bitRead(x, 20).longValue() * 4;
            position4 = bitRead(x, 26).longValue() * 8;
            position5 = bitRead(x, 31).longValue() * 16;

            index = position1 + position2 + position3 + position4 + position5;
            System.out.println("the encrypted index is " + index);

            b1 = bitRead(x, 0);
            b2 = bitRead(x, 16);
            int intIndex = (int) index;
            b3 = bitRead(KeeLoq_NLF, intIndex);
            b4 = keyBitVal;

            bitVal = b1.xor(b2).xor(b3).xor(b4);
            BigInteger tempx = x.shiftRight(1);
            x = tempx.xor(bitVal);
                        //bitVal = bitRead(x,0) ^ bitRead(x, 16) ^ bitRead(KeeLoq_NLF,index) ^ keyBitVal;
            //x = (x>>1) ^ bitVal<<31;
        }
        return x;
    }

    BigInteger Decrypt(BigInteger data) {
        BigInteger x = data;
        int keyBitNo;
        long index;
        long position1, position2, position3, position4, position5;
        BigInteger keyBitVal, bitVal;
        BigInteger b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

        for (int r = 0; r < 528; r++) {
            keyBitNo = (15 - r) & 63;
            if (keyBitNo < 32) {
                keyBitVal = bitRead(_keyLow, keyBitNo);
            } else {
                keyBitVal = bitRead(_keyHigh, keyBitNo - 32);
            }

            position1 = bitRead(x, 0).longValue() * 1;
            position2 = bitRead(x, 8).longValue() * 2;
            position3 = bitRead(x, 19).longValue() * 4;
            position4 = bitRead(x, 25).longValue() * 8;
            position5 = bitRead(x, 30).longValue() * 16;

            index = position1 + position2 + position3 + position4 + position5;

            System.out.println("The Decrypted index is " + index);

            b1 = bitRead(x, 31);
            b2 = bitRead(x, 15);
            int intIndex = (int) index;
            b3 = bitRead(KeeLoq_NLF, intIndex);
            b4 = keyBitVal;

            bitVal = b1.xor(b2).xor(b3).xor(b4);
            BigInteger tempx = x.shiftLeft(1);
            x = tempx.xor(bitVal);


            //index = 1 * bitRead(x,0) + 2 * bitRead(x,8) + 4 * bitRead(x,19) + 8 * bitRead(x,25) + 16 * bitRead(x,30);
            // bitVal = bitRead(x,31) ^ bitRead(x, 15) ^ bitRead(KeeLoq_NLF,index) ^ keyBitVal;
            //   x = (x<<1) ^ bitVal;


        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger highKey = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(66));
        BigInteger lowKey = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(35));
        KeeLoq KeeLoq_file = new KeeLoq(highKey, lowKey);
        System.out.println("The KeeLoq Code is " + KeeLoq_file.KeeLoq_code);
        BigInteger EncryptedBigInt = KeeLoq_file.Encrypt(KeeLoq_file.KeeLoq_NLF);
        System.out.println("The Encrypted BigIntegerValue is " + EncryptedBigInt);
        System.out.println("The Encrypted integer value is " + EncryptedBigInt.intValue());
        BigInteger DecryptedBigInt = KeeLoq_file.Decrypt(EncryptedBigInt);
        System.out.println("The Decrypted BigIntegerValue is " + DecryptedBigInt);
        System.out.println("The Decrypted integer value is " + DecryptedBigInt.intValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: How big are the decrypted indices supposed to get?

Comment: This has been running for a few minutes on my computer and I'm fairly certain that the `BigIntegers` are getting big enough that the printed decrypted indices are overflowing...

Comment: Yea, I noticed that too.  The encrypted indexes are all the same size while the decrypted indexes seem to keep growing.  I'm not sure if that is a problem that is caused from loss of precision from converting BigInteger or the decryption algorithm itself.


I would think that the indexes would remain the same size.  So I'm going try to just reverse the encryption algorithm and see how far that gets me.

Comment: Yeah, `Encrypt()` takes significantly less time to run than `Decrypt()`. It doesn't appear that you have any obvious errors in `Decrypt()`, so to be honest I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: One more thing; `longs` in Java don't have the same range of values as `unsigned longs` in C++, so if the sum of the positions is too large you'll get something different from the C++ code.

Comment: Quick and dirty profiling tells me that most of the time decrypting is spent in the lines where you assign to `b1`, `b2`, etc. and the block of code immediately following that.

Comment: Specifically, it appears to be the `xor()` calls. Using a debugger and stepping through the code yields oddly long pauses on those calls. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I figured a way to decrypt it using properties of XOR.


It's not really ideal but it works.  I doubt I can find a ideal solution without delving deeply into the specifics BigInteger class so this will work.  Thanks to everyone that responded.

Comment: public BigInteger DecryptAlt(BigInteger data){
        BigInteger x = data.xor(KeeLoq_NLF);
        BigInteger y = data.xor(x);
        return y;
    }

Comment: That's a rather interesting solution. If that's all it takes, you have to wonder why the author of the library went through all the trouble with the other code...

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I think I got it! (or at least part of it)

The issue is at least partially in this line: (got the wrong line at first, sorry)

```
 int intIndex = (int) index;
```

When `index` gets large enough, `(int) index` will overflow to a large negative value. Guess what happens when you pass that into `bitRead()`?

Now, why this overflow happens in `Decrypt()` and not in `Encrypt()`, I'm not sure... I'll look later once I get some more rest, but hopefully this is a start.

You can increase the memory space available by running the program with the -Xmx flag. For example, to run with max 4 gigabytes of ram you'd use -Xmx4G

In Eclipse, this can by set by right-clicking on the file, going to Properties --> Run/Debug Settings --> click on the launch configuration --> Edit --> Arguments tab --> VM arguments --> type in the flag.

If you're running out of memory with Java's `BigInteger` class, I'm not certain that using any other arbitrary-precision library would get you very far if the numbers actually get that large.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in the bitRead function: Here is the documentation from arduino:

> Syntax bitRead(x, n)
>
> Parameters x: the number from which to read
>
> n: which bit to read, starting at 0 for the least-significant
>   (rightmost) bit
>
> Returns the value of the bit (0 or 1).

Your function returns larger values like 3824712.